# How to connect Pi 3 to computer screen or TV?

Tags: screen, connection

I am new to using Pi and know little about programming and hacking. I have been having issues with connecting my Pi 3 to a moniter or a screen of some sort, I also cant ping it. I put in `ping raspberrypi` and it gives me `Ping request could not find host raspberrypi. Please check the name and try again.` 
 The Pi is running Raspbian OS. Along with everybodys questions my AMP and Voltage is 5V and 2.5A im using the wall brick that came with the PI

Comment: Clarify what you are trying to do? Because pinging the pi and connecting it to a screen are two separate operations. You connect it to a screen with an HDMI cable, with the port located on the side of the pi. Pinging the Pi requires that it is on your local area network, and responsive to internet requests. How exactly do you want to set the Pi up?

Comment: So what im trying to do mostly is connecting it to a screen, but ive tried with an HDMI cable and made sure i was on the right sorce but still nothing. I also am having an issue with pinging it but i know the IP adress and still I get a error saying that '(IP adress) refuses to connect'.

Comment: Which power cable are you using? The RPi 3 requires 2.5 Amps, rather that the usual 2.1 Amps output by standard phone chargers.

Comment: In addition to what others have said:

Comment: If your monitor has more than 1 input, like most, you need to make sure it has HDMI input selected, usually using buttons on the monitor, or that it will automatically find active inputs. Assuming yes, what makes you think your Pi is booted up to a state to be producing output, since you cannot log in locally (no display) or via network (no ping)? The green LED indicates memory access, so when you boot, you should see it flashing for about 30 seconds. Are you using a known-working memory card, known to work on your exact Pi? Is that how you "know the IP adress"? (*)

Comment: (*) Note: IP might not be the same if you booted it connected to somebody else's network and it is configured to use DHCP.

Comment: ok, so some things we need to know to help you: how do you know the IP address, where do you get it from? What is the voltage and amp output of the power source you are using (should be in small writing on the big wall block)? Could it be that the monitor you are using has 2 HDMI input modes? Do you have access to another linux machine to try an ssh?

Comment: I found the IP address by loging into my modem, I know its the rspberry pi's because its name is Raspberry pi. The wall brick says "Input: 100-240V AC" "Output: 5V-2.5A" the moniter has both DMI and VGA not HDMI, my TV has several HDMI modes and i checked them all. What is an SSH?